# Use Laravel 4 Encrypter within a namespace

Tags: php, encryption, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to `use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;` within a namespace which I created. The code really exists in my file.

**Problem:**
I want laravel to use the key set under 'app/config/app.php' automaticly. However the constructer wants me to set it properly with my hands.

To see how this task is handled by Taylor Otwell, I searched for an example and saw that under "Illuminate\Cache\DatabaseStore", it was set to `$encrypter` as an instance, using constructer. Tylor also uses a function to `getEncrypter();` as follows:

```
/**
 * Get the encrypter instance.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter
 */
public function getEncrypter()
{
    return $this->encrypter;
}
```

Because I want my class to be automaticly loaded with a function in another class; I can't use IoC Container.

Here are my functions and params:

```
/**
 * The encrypter to be used for several reasons.
 */
protected $encrypter = "Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter";

/**
* Returns the encrypter.
* 
* @return Object
*/
public function getEncrypter()
{
    return $this->createEncrypter();
}

/**
 * Creates a new encrypter object.
 *
 * @param  $string  $encrypter
 * @return Obj $encrypter instance
 */
public function createEncrypter()
{
    $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->encrypter, '\\');

    return new $class;
}

/**
 * Sets the crypter used by MyFacadeName
 * 
 * @param  Encrypter  $encrypter
 */
public function setEncrypter($encrypter)
{
    $this->encrypter = $encrypter;
}
```

What is the difference makes the parser think that Taylor is right and I am wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Laravel and you cannot access the Facades because they have not been loaded/initialized yet:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::get('app.key');
```

your last resort might be to access the `$app` via $GLOBALS:

```
public function createEncrypter()
{
    $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->encrypter, '\\');

    return new $class($GLOBALS['app']['config']->get('app.key'));
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the first thing laravel did was boot the IoC and it gets autoloaded into every page that has access to the other framework elements?

Comment: You're right. IoC is available but Facades (app/config/app.php) might not be loaded yet. Just edited.